# Add item in Windows XP context menu to open path in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-xp

I'd like to add an option in my context menu to be able to right click on a file and view the containing folder in Windows Explorer.  Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: If you are able to right click on the file then aren't you already in it's 'containing folder' in order to view the file icon?

Comment: No, I'm using Agent Ransack and I'd like to add this to the results of a search.

Comment: Never used Agent Ransack, but is the context menu the standard Windows Explorer context menu?  As in, does it have the Send To option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the latest version of [Agent Ransack 2010](http://www.mythicsoft.com/page.aspx?type=agentransack&page=home).

It has an "Explore here" option in the right-click context menu.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to be clear on what you're right-clicking. If it's an actual file in Explorer, you're already looking at the containing folder (as was mentioned by Daisetsu).

In the more likely case where you're right-clicking a shortcut on the desktop or in the Start menu, then there's a simple registry hack that does the job perfectly at http://www.askvg.com/how-to-get-windows-vista-and-7s-open-file-location-option-in-xp/.

Here's the hack's REG file contents:

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
;Created by Vishal Gupta for AskVG.com
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\File Location]
@="Open &File Location"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\File Location\command]
@="\"explorer.exe\" /select,\"%1\""

Answer (score 0):

-- *based on [Vishal Gupta](https://www.askvg.com/about/)'s [article](https://www.askvg.com/how-to-get-windows-vista-and-7s-open-file-location-option-in-xp/) and [boot13](https://superuser.com/users/41423/boot13)'s [answer](https://superuser.com/a/164436)...*  --

Here's an improved version:

- New name 'Explore here' (instead of 'Open File Location').
- Menu item appears in top of the context menu.
- It has an icon next to it.

Instructions:

1. Create empty REG-file
2. Copy + paste registry script and save file.
3. Run the REG-file.

File name:

```
Add 'Explore here' option in Windows XP.reg
```

Contents:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\File Location]
@="&Explore here"
"Icon"="imageres.dll,203"
"Position"="Top"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\File Location\command]
@="\"explorer.exe\" /select,\"%1\""
```

note: These registry changes were tested in Windows 10, not Windows XP.